# How can I use both @freezed and @riverpod annotations

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want my state to use `@freezed` and I also want provider to be generated automatically with `@riverpod` annotation:

```
enum TemperatureUnits {
  celsius,
  kelvin,
}

enum UnitSystem {
  metric,
  imperial,
}

@freezed
@riverpod
class Settings with _$Settings {
  const factory Settings({
    @Default(TemperatureUnits.celsius) TemperatureUnits temperatureUnits,
    @Default(UnitSystem.metric) UnitSystem unitSystem,
  }) = _Settings;

  factory Settings.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$SettingsFromJson(json);

  @override
  Settings build() {
    final sharedPreferences = ref.read(sharedPreferencesProvider); // ref is not defined, how do I access sharedPreferencesProvider here?
    final json = sharedPreferences.getString("userSettings");
    if (json != null) {
      return Settings.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
    }
    return const Settings();
  }

  void save() {
    final sharedPreferences = ref.read(sharedPreferencesProvider); // ref is not defined, how do I access sharedPreferencesProvider here?
    sharedPreferences.setString("userSettings", jsonEncode(this.toJson()));
  }
}
```

I want to add extra method for saving `Settings` to `shared_preferences` and for this I want to use `sharedPreferencesProvider`. How do I get it into my `Settings` class?

If combining those two is not a good idea, what would be a better approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing 2 things: the model, and the service.
I would recommend to separate these 2, to have a better separation of concerns.

First, I would create a model, using `@freezed`, like so:

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'settings.freezed.dart';
part 'settings.g.dart';

@freezed
class Settings with _$Settings {
  const factory Settings({
    @Default(TemperatureUnits.celsius) TemperatureUnits temperatureUnits,
    @Default(UnitSystem.metric) UnitSystem unitSystem,
  }) = _Settings;

  factory Settings.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$SettingsFromJson(json);
}

enum TemperatureUnits {
  celsius,
  kelvin,
}

enum UnitSystem {
  metric,
  imperial,
}
```

Then I would create a service using this model, using `@riverpod`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:coup_de_pouce/notifiers/settings.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

part 'settings_service.g.dart';

@riverpod
class SettingsService extends _$SettingsService {
  @override
  Settings build() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ref.read(sharedPreferencesProvider);
    final String? json = sharedPreferences.getString("userSettings");
    if (json != null) {
      return Settings.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
    }
    return const Settings();
  }

  void save() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ref.read(sharedPreferencesProvider);
    sharedPreferences.setString("userSettings", jsonEncode(state.toJson()));
  }
}
```

This will generate a `settingsServiceProvider`, that you can use this way:

```dart
ref.read(settingsServiceProvider.notifier).save();
```

Note that I did not update the code to load and save the settings, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here.
Here the provider generated is a NotifierProvider, I'm not sure this is useful in your case.
Moreover, this service only loads Settings from localPreferences, and save it.
I don't see any method to update the settings.
You could add this method to the service for instance :

```dart
void updateSettings(Settings settings) {
  state = settings;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, with 2 classes, `Settings` and `SettingsService`, this looks much better.